# Javascript: return true not working

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, firefox

I need to prevent a textbox from entering alphabets and any other special characters except dot character. Here is my function:

```
    function key_block(current_element,event){
                var str = current_element.val();
                //alertify.log(str);
                var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9.]+$");
                var key = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);

                if (regex.test(str)) {
                   //event.preventDefault();
                   return true;
                } else {
                     current_element.val('');

                     return false;
                }
            }
if(key_block($(this),e)){
              //allow typing
            }
```

The code works fine in Chrome Browser. But in Firefox, this is not working fine. I get value "true" for regex.test(str) in firefox. But I don't know why this does not allow me to type the code. Can anyone find the real problem here?

Comment: provide a fiddle please

Comment: unrelated, but why not just use `/^[0-9.]+$/.test(str)`?

Comment: If you asking about regexp it works the same in Chrome and Firefox. I've just tested it in consoles.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're filtering the incoming event's `charCode` to block unwanted characters. If that's the case, I think you need to test `key` instead of `str`:

```
if (regex.test(key)) {
```